# bower install > TypeError: msecs must be a number

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower, bower-install

I recently upgraded to `node.js v0.12.7` and I have an issue with `bower install` when I want to install dependencies into a project folder:

```
$ bower install 
timers.js:165
    throw new TypeError('msecs must be a number');
          ^
TypeError: msecs must be a number
    at Object.exports.enroll (timers.js:165:11)
    at Socket.setTimeout (net.js:337:12)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (_http_client.js:565:10)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:199:16)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at tickOnSocket (_http_client.js:493:7)
    at _http_client.js:504:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

$ node --version
v0.12.7
```

I saw that there is some related issues with `node.js v0.12` and this error message that says that **it requires options with `timeout` argument defined**.

So I tried to add a timeout in my folder parent tree in each `.bowerrc`

```
{
  "registry": "http://bower.mycompany.com",
  "timeout": "15000",
  "directory": "public/lib"
}
```

But it didn't worked as expected. Same error always thrown.

Comment: Your timeout is a string, not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep)'s comment, I edited `.bowerrc` to match a **defined and number typed!**" timeout field.

### So I clarify the solution for those who get the same error after upgrading to `node.js > v0.10` :

If you  have a `.bowerrc` file in your project folder or parent folder tree, you must fill it with a number typed `timeout` (for example `15000`) as like this :

```
{
  "timeout": 15000
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by passing timeout as number instead of string (which clearly mentioned in error)
I got similar error in emailjs

```
timers.js:289
    throw new TypeError('"msecs" argument must be a number');
    ^
TypeError: "msecs" argument must be a number
    at Object.exports.enroll (timers.js:289:11)
    at TLSSocket.Socket.setTimeout (net.js:321:12)
    at new SMTPResponse (node_modules/emailjs/smtp/response.js:75:10)
    at Object.exports.monitor (node_modules/emailjs/smtp/response.js:80:10)
    at Object.SMTP.connect (node_modules/emailjs/smtp/smtp.js:163:33)
    at Object.Client._connect (node_modules/emailjs/smtp/client.js:78:17)
    at Object.Client._poll (node_modules/emailjs/smtp/client.js:28:18)
    at node_modules/emailjs/smtp/client.js:115:21
    at Object.Message.valid (node_modules/emailjs/smtp/message.js:180:10)
    at Object.Client.send (node_modules/emailjs/smtp/client.js:93:14)
```

I think you can use

```
{
  "registry": "http://bower.mycompany.com",
  "timeout": 15000,                        //remove "
  "directory": "public/lib"
}
```

instad of:

```
{
  "registry": "http://bower.mycompany.com",
  "timeout": "15000",
  "directory": "public/lib"
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to mention the same error I faced in using emailjs.
During  sever.send() call.